# Iterate over list in a cell to countif it meets a criteria in another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering if there's a way to iterate over a list of values in a single cell, to then look up the value of each item in that last, and then to count how many times it occurs in another list.  I would also be ok if we just put a list of the qualifying IDs in this cell. Here's a link to a demo of the data (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aoFIzQ9gjNYLQqpWO_6UVjn_JO9aWFSNOMyrT1VPK-0/edit?usp=sharing).

As an example, I would want to know how many of the IDs in cell B9 use "software" tools (J3:J). I would then place the count of this in D9.  So, D9 should either say "4" or have the following IDs: 28, 72, 189, 534.  E9 would say "2" or have following IDs: 141, 856, and F9 would say, "1" or have the ID: 664.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

paste in D9 and drag to the right:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IFNA(FILTER($H:$H, $J:$J=D$2, 
 MATCH($H:$H, FLATTEN(SPLIT($B9, ",")), 0))))
```

and in C9:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(""&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, $D9:$F9), "[0-9]+", ))+1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution, @player0! I'm able to see what each piece of the code is doing and make it work in the larger dataset. Can I just say how awesome the online tech community is? I appreciate you taking the time to lend your expertise to my problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like an array solution (i.e., one formula per column that produces all results for all rows in that column), try this:

1.) For best performance, regardless of approach, you should keep each sheet trimmed to only the max number of columns and rows you anticipate ever needing. So I recommend that you first select and delete Rows 201 to 1001, and delete Column L to X (or delete any rows and columns beyond the maximum number you need in your real sheet). The formula proposed below will work whether you take this step or not; but you'll improve performance speed if you take this step, because every array formula must process all rows its provided, whether blank or not.

2.) Select and delete everything from D3:F (i.e., D3 as the upper left of the range and the last row in F as the bottom right of the range).

3.) Place the following formula into cell D3:

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(LOWER(VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT($B3:$B&REPT(",0",100),",",1),ROWS($B3:$B),100),$H:$J,3,FALSE))),LOWER(D2))*1,SEQUENCE(100,1,1,0)))`

You will immediately see results fill in for all rows in Column D.

4.) Drag this formula to the right, into cells E3 and F3. Results for those columns will fill in accordingly for all rows.

The formula allows for up 100 comma-separated values in each cell of B3:B. However, if you think you won't ever have more than, say, 50, change the three instances of `100` in the formula to `50` (or to just above whatever you think the maximum number of values per cell will ever be). The closer you can get to that max, the more optimal the processing time will be.

**In addition...**

If you'd like to replace your Col-C values with a single array formula:

1.) Delete everything from C3:C.

2.) Place the following variation of your original Col-C formula in cell C3:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,LEN(B3:B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3:B,",",""))+1))`

Comment: Erik, thanks a million for this involved answer and the additional tips on optimizing my formulae. I'm going to dig into the documentation on each of these functions to try and understand what each is doing and put it all together.  I really appreciate you taking the time.  Happy holidays!

Comment: You're welcome. If the formula is, in fact, working as intended, please do mark the answer post as "Best Answer." This allows the contributor community to see at a glance from the dashboard which issues have been fully resolved; and it allows future site visitors to most quickly find the answers that may be related to their own searches based on similar issues.